# Minify all of sails.js served html

Tags: sails.js

I need my [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) app to serve minified html to the user. So it is hard to read by the user. Has anyone done this before ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

This works for me:
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2188#issuecomment-56994236

In **config/views.js**:

```
var minify = require('html-minifier').minify;
var ejs = require('ejs-locals');
var parsing = function(path,options,fn) {
    options.locals = options.locals || {};
    options.locals._layoutFile = 'layout.ejs';
    ejs(path, options, function(err, str){
      str = minify(str,{collapseWhitespace: true, removeComments: true});
      return fn(err, str);
    });

};

module.exports.views = {
  engine: {
    ext: 'ejs',
    fn: parsing
  },
  layout: false
};
```

Comment: Can I not use this with partials ? I just tried and could not get it working, There is a error code 30

Comment: I will post all my errors and the files here so then you could prob help me out.

Comment: How can we use this for multiple layouts ?

Comment: I guess you could create a "sails.config.myLayout" and use that as a global definition of "layout".

Comment: Is this method does not put much load on the processor at every request? And I've tried https://kangax.github.io/html-minifier/ with my very complex EJS files. Unfortunately it gave error often. Is there another way/library?

Comment: "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined\n    at collapseWhitespace (myproject/node_modules/html-minifier/src/htmlminifier.js:40:14)\n  ... Does this still work? I get this error on my Sails.js App.